# Splitting the traffic to different areas in a ASP.NET Core 5 MVC application

Tags: webforms, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm migrating an ASP.NET webforms app to ASP.NET Core 5 MVC. I will have 10 **areas** where the **Views** and **Controllers** are almost the same but with minor changes. I want to split the traffic to different areas based on the route and see how they are performing.

What feature does ASP.NET Core 5 MVC provide to split the traffic to different areas?

Comment: I updated the question with *ASP.NET Core MVC*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What feature does ASP.NET Core 5 MVC provide to split the traffic to different areas?

You can configure area routes in conventional routing to make incoming request(s) can be matched to corresponding area endpoint(s).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-5.0#add-area-route

Besides, if any specific scenario that requires capturing request(s) and do custom code logic to redirect to expected area endpoint based on some specific custom rules, you can try to achieve it in middleware.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#branch-the-middleware-pipeline

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Will the URL change from the initial landing to subsequently if I do the redirection in the middleware? We want to compare the performance of the webform and the new MVC app, so the URLs should not change.